# How to prevent Beautiful Soup Running Slowly

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, proxy

I'm trying to scrape about 360 URLs off a university library's website(They don't have a open API)

The code ran fine the first time until the final 5 URLs.

Then it had an "IndexError".

I added an exception for that and ran the code again. And now it runs super slowly. About 1 minute per loop.

Is the website throttling me? Are there any workarounds to this?

```
def extract_page(df, page_list):
    # Create counter
    counter=0
    # Looping through all existing URLs
    for url in df["dc.identifier.uri"]:
        counter+=1

        try:
            # headers
            headers = requests.utils.default_headers()
            headers.update({
                'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/52.0',
            })
            # Using requests and BS to extract content
            r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
            soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)
            # Creating empty list to nest all URLs on the page
            url_list = []
            # Drilling into the extracted text to find all instances of "-PHD"
            for a in soup.find_all('a', href=True):
                if "-PHD" in a['href']:
                    abstract_url = "https://repository.nie.edu.sg" + a['href']
                    url_list.append(abstract_url)
            # Append first instance of this
            page_list.append(url_list[0])
            # Creating a time delay to be polite to the server
            time.sleep(0.3)
            # Print progress report and flush
            sys.stdout.write('\r'+ "PROCESSING: "+ str(counter) + "/" + str(df.shape[0]) +  " >>> " + url + " >>> " + url_list[0])
            time.sleep(randint(1,3))

        except (OSError,MaxRetryError, ConnectionError, IndexError) as e:
            counter+=1
            page_list.append("Error Encountered.")
    # Creating a new column in the dataset
    df["abstract_page_url"] = page_list
    print("\r>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>COMPLETED ", counter,"/", nie.shape[0])
    return df
```

Answer (score 1):

Pretty unlikely that they are throttling you with that small amount of requests.

Typically when I encounter slow requests, I like to use multithreading to speed up the process. That way, the slower requests don't stop other requests. (Only scraping 360 might make this overkill but if they actually take a minute, this will save a lot of time.)

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor 
with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers = 25) as ex:
   responses = ex.map(page_to_scrape_request, list_of_urls)

   for response in responses:
      parse_response(response)
```

This requires creating two functions - one for just submitting the requests and another for parsing the html with beautiful soup. I'm sure there are other ways to do it but this has worked well for me. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

The reason may be some urls taking long time to respond.. you can set Max time out for each requests..
`r = requests.get(url, headers=headers, timeout=30)`